# EMACS: Auto run a function when open a new buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp, text-editor, emacs24

How can I auto run a function when open a new buffer, say `text-scale-adjust`.

Comment: There's a `find-file-hook` along with mode specific hooks.

Comment: @abo-abo: Does not help with non-file buffers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A slightly more detailed version of abo-abo's answer:

```
(add-hook 'find-file-hook
          '(lambda () (text-scale-adjust 1)))
```

This will run for all files you visit.  You can look at mode-specific hooks if you want to tailor which types of files/buffers get this treatment.

Comment: Placing a quote in front of `(lambda . . .` on a recent version of Emacs will create an error message (when starting Emacs or loading the file) stating that there is an extra quote.  `lambda` is self-quoting, so the quote should be removed.

Comment: Does not help with non-file buffers.

Comment: agree @Drew, it doesnt help with non-file buffers

Answer (score 3):

You could take a look at these *hooks*, as well:

- `after-change-major-mode-hook`
- `change-major-mode-hook`
- `change-majory-mode-after-body-hook`
- `first-change-hook`
- `window-configuration-change-hook`

*But can you clarify what the aim really is?*

If you just want to **make *all buffers display with larger or smaller text***, then it is enough to do *one* of the following:

- Choose from the menu bar: `Options` > `Set Default Font...`.
- Put this in your init file: `(set-frame-font "THE FONT YOU WANT, WITH THE PROPER SIZE" nil t)`
- Set the default font size for all frames to what you want, at the outset, simply by customizing `default-frame-alist` wrt frame parameter `font`.

IOW, set the font size for your frames, rather than scaling the text of all buffers.